# how to upload Image in Blazor server app and save the image in the folder (& in the server) save that url to the db

Tags: sql-server, file-upload, blazor, blazor-server-side

> Ive to upload image along with the item and save this images in the
> local folder and the server image repository and the image url should
> be passed to db. (Have to combine the filepath and the physicalpath  )
> The code  below is not working.

```
   @code{
         .
    .
    .
    .
    
                        foreach (var file in args.Files)
                        {
            
                            var size = file.FileInfo.Size;
                            path = "wwwroot\images\" + file.FileInfo.Name;
                            FileStream filestream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                            file.Stream.WriteTo(filestream);
                            filestream.Close();
                            file.Stream.Close();
                            var pathUrl = path;
             
                        }.
.
.
.

        arg.Data.ItemImage = path;
    
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hy,
I used this dev express control for achieving this :

https://docs.devexpress.com/Blazor/DevExpress.Blazor.DxUpload

It needs some tuning butt in case you follow the examples it works great.
Also make sure you have write premission in the folder your willing to save the files.

Give it a try, and let me know in case you got stuck.

Best regards,

Mathias

Comment: i will .Thank so much for looking in to this issue.